# iOS: landscape to portrait resized not to full

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I have a navigation bar at the top of my nib, followed by a toolbar, and a webview. This is all vertically.

I basically implemented an in app browser.

If I launch my browser in portrait mode and switch to landscape. Everything works fine.

However, if I launch it in landscape mode, a portion of the right hand size is missing.

and when I switch from landscape to portrait mode, the right portion is still missing.

I think if I fixed the way it launches in landscape mode, it will be fixed.

How do I put interface builder in landscape mode/solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the autosizing settings are correct for your navigation bar? I think typically it should have flexible left margin, flexible width and also flexible right margin.

Answer (score 0):

You check your nib and set the autosize of toolbar navigation bar and webview and then run and try I think that will work fine.Just try and confirm us.